# Wordpress loop ignore newest post in query

Tags: wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to pull out all of the posts that have a meta value of Main, while trying to ignore the newest post created. I've looked [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) (WordPress site https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) but I can't figure out a way to ignore the newest post. It can't be by a set date, because it needs to always ignore the newest post.

```
                        $args = array(
                            'order'                 => 'DESC',
                            'meta_key'              => 'main_story',
                            'meta_value'            => 'Main',

                            'meta_query'        => array(

                                'relation'      => 'NOT IN',

                                array(
                                    'key'             => 'main_story',
                                    'value'           => Main,
                                    'posts_per_page'  => 1,
                                    'order'           => 'DESC',
                                    ),

                                )
                            );
```

I thought trying it this way not not get the newest post, but it hasn't worked. Is there an opposite of getting the meta_query, like ignore_meta_query, but you know, that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with your posted code...but you're looking for the [`offset` parameter of `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

> `offset` *(int)* - number of post to displace or pass over. **Warning:** Setting the `offset` parameter overrides/ignores the `paged` parameter and breaks pagination. The `offset` parameter is ignored when `'posts_per_page'=> -1` is used.

```
$args = array(
    'offset' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_key' => 'main_story',
    'meta_value' => 'Main',
    'meta_compare' => 'NOT',
);
```

Comment: Just so I get this right, using offset will mean if I use it where I would usually have pagination, means that it would no longer be able to be paginated?

Comment: Correct, but your query doesn't include pagination arguments, so this shouldn't affect you.

Comment: That's true for the moment, but if it were to include pagination in the future, is there another way to do this?

Comment: In that case, I would just grab the `paged` parameter before querying, and use it to alter the query (increment it up one page): `'paged' => intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) + 1,`